# Is it possible to change the 'dot' shape in a QR Code generated by ZXing?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

Currently, I'm using ZXing to generate QR Codes. I have no problems in generating and reading the codes, and can change the colour scheme without any issues. I was wondering if it is possible to change the shape of the generated codes from the traditional squares to 'dots' or circles using ZXing?

I've seen images and examples of this, but I haven't seen any example solutions using ZXing.

Looking for something like:

[image]

If it is possible to do with ZXing? I would appreciate any example code.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @Daniel unfortunately not. If you do though, please let me know.

Comment: See also extremely similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419511/generate-qr-codes-with-custom-dot-shapes-using-zxing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library doesn't render the QR code actually, excepting that there's a bit of utility code to write it out as an image in the javase/ module. So I think you would mostly be writing your own code or copying a bit of that. It's not hard. I don't think it's a great idea to render this way as it hurts readability, but probably still substantially works.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. I ended up forking zxing and using [JitPack](https://jitpack.io) to include my fork with Maven. I implemented functionality for RGB masking and for drawing circles and outlined squares as dot shapes. Here is the repository: https://github.com/flotwig/zxing