# How can I generate a QR Code like this in C#

Tags: c#, qr-code

This qr code is generated in https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/
[image]

currently I am looking into C# qrcoder open source  on how to change the body shape and the eye frame shape and eye frame ball.

Any advise what type of qrcode body is this and how to make a similar one.

Thank you

Comment: It was not me but I may explain possible reasons. First, people may suspect your post is intended to advertise the QRcode site. Second, ask the [recommendation of a lib](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource?rq=1) is actually consider off-topic when it comes to SO guidelines.

Comment: A valid question.
If you download a copy of the code from : https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder
Open the QRCoder project. I recommend using the SvgQRCode class. See method GetGraphic.
Edit starting at lines : 

StringBuilder svgFile = new StringBuilder($@"<svg version=""1.1"" baseProfile=""full"" shape-rendering=""crispEdges"" {svgSizeAttributes} xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"">");
            svgFile.AppendLine($@"<rect x=""0"" y=""0"" width=""{CleanSvgVal(qrSize)}"" height=""{CleanSvgVal(qrSize)}"" fill=""{lightColorHex}"" />");

Comment: I'm currently working on this myself. I'm happy to provide further information if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use its paid API for long term: https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/qr-code-api-with-logo

Or you could get it via Post request at its generation site (free), I don't know how many requests could be, but I'm sure they will restrict it.

I took a quick request in Postman, you could [readmore](https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/qr-code-api-with-logo) to find more attributes you want

```
{"data":"https://www.qrcode-monkey.com","config":{"body":"pointed-in-smooth","eye":"frame0","eyeBall":"ball5","erf1":[],"erf2":[],"erf3":[],"brf1":[],"brf2":[],"brf3":[],"bodyColor":"#000000","bgColor":"#FFFFFF","eye1Color":"#000000","eye2Color":"#000000","eye3Color":"#000000","eyeBall1Color":"#E91212","eyeBall2Color":"#E91212","eyeBall3Color":"#E91212","gradientColor1":"#FCE709","gradientColor2":"#009EFD","gradientType":"linear","gradientOnEyes":false,"logo":"#google-play","logoMode":"clean"},"size":1000,"download":"imageUrl","file":"svg"}
```

Request

```
Request URL: https://qr-generator.qrcode.studio/qr/custom
Request Method: POST
```

Response

```
{"imageUrl":"\/\/qr-generator.qrcode.studio\/tmp\/dbbc4665a5bf813daf84da4445edcea8.svg"}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Aside from the API. Are there any open source that can configure the body shape and the eye frame?

Comment: @Mico Then you might custom your own code in [Zxing.net](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net). It's quite abroad to custom and I still recommend you use via API. You might reference how [java code implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59955617/3789481) to know it's complex

Comment: Thank you. I will check this and the API